# Как создать кнопку в aiogram

Tags: python

Прошу помочь я хотел создать кнопку

использую aiogram

Answer (score 0):

```
keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    buttons = ["С пюрешкой", "Без пюрешки"]
    keyboard.add(*buttons)
```